# Date Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM OverFlow error SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime, console-application, sqlbulkcopy

I am reading data from an access db and storing it in a temporary sql table then truncate the main sql table and insert the fresh data set and i am accomplishing that task using the code below but the datetime is giving me issues:

```
Console.WriteLine("NetWeightTracking-Abilene Started");
            var du = new System.Data.DataTable();
            string accdbConnStrabk = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NetWeightAbk"].ToString();
            using (var accdbConn = new OdbcConnection(accdbConnStrabk))
            {
                using (var da = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Net Weight Tracking]", accdbConn))
                {
                    da.Fill(du);

                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("DataTable filled from NetWeight db NetWeightTracking-Abilene - Row count: {0}", du.Rows.Count, DateTime.Now.ToString());

            string sqlConnStrabk = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconabk"].ToString();
            using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnStrabk))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE #NetWeightTracking ([Date] [datetime] NULL,[Unit UPC Base Item] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[Item (Optional)] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[Preset Number] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[Product Group] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[Shift] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[Rotation Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[BBD] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[Operator Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[Supervisor] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[Production Line] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[Bagger Number] [float] NULL,[Start Time] [datetime] NULL,[Stop Time] [datetime] NULL,[Under Counts] [float] NULL,[Label Wt on Pkg (g)] [float] NULL,[Machine Tare Wt (g)] [float] NULL,[Actual Tare Wt (g)] [float] NULL,[Verify Target Wt (g)] [float] NULL,[Total Count (Proper)] [float] NULL,[Mean Gross (g)] [float] NULL,[Rptd Mean Net (g)] [float] NULL,[Std Dev (g)] [float] NULL,[Max (g)] [float] NULL,[Min (g)] [float] NULL,[TNE (g)] [float] NULL,[Comments] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[Field1] [datetime] NULL,[Field2] [datetime] NULL,[Field3] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[Field4] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[Field5] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[Field6] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[Field7] [nvarchar](255) NULL, [Row] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                using (SqlTransaction tran = sqlConn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (var sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, tran))
                        {

                            sbc.BatchSize = 100;
                            sbc.NotifyAfter = 100;
                            sbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 100;
                            sbc.DestinationTableName = "#NetWeightTracking";
                            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                            sbc.WriteToServer(du);
                            Console.WriteLine("After Datatable", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                        cmd.Transaction = tran;
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM #NetWeightTracking";
                        Console.WriteLine("SqlBulkCopy complete. Temp table row count: {0}", cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                        cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Net Weight Tracking]";
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Console.WriteLine("Truncated NetWeightTrackingTable");

                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Net Weight Tracking] ([Date],[Unit UPC Base Item],[Item (Optional)],[Preset Number],[Product Group],[Shift],[Rotation Code],[BBD],[Operator Name],[Supervisor],[Production Line],[Bagger Number],[Start Time],[Stop Time],[Under Counts],[Label Wt on Pkg (g)],[Machine Tare Wt (g)],[Actual Tare Wt (g)],[Verify Target Wt (g)],[Total Count (Proper)],[Mean Gross (g)],[Rptd Mean Net (g)],[Std Dev (g)],[Max (g)],[Min (g)],[TNE (g)],[Comments],[Field1],[Field2],[Field3])  SELECT Z.[Date],Z.[Unit UPC Base Item],Z.[Item (Optional)],Z.[Preset Number],Z.[Product Group],Z.[Shift],Z.[Rotation Code],Z.[BBD],Z.[Operator Name],Z.[Supervisor],Z.[Production Line],Z.[Bagger Number],Z.[Start Time],Z.[Stop Time],Z.[Under Counts],Z.[Label Wt on Pkg (g)],Z.[Machine Tare Wt (g)],Z.[Actual Tare Wt (g)],Z.[Verify Target Wt (g)],Z.[Total Count (Proper)],Z.[Mean Gross (g)],Z.[Rptd Mean Net (g)],Z.[Std Dev (g)],Z.[Max (g)],Z.[Min (g)],Z.[TNE (g)],Z.[Comments],Z.[Field1],Z.[Field2],Z.[Field3] FROM  #NetWeightTracking Z";
                        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS m FROM [dbo].[Net Weight Tracking]";
                        Console.WriteLine("Inserted Records into NetWeightTracking:{0}", cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                    }
                    tran.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
```

**The issue is caused by the date column**
any help will be greatly appreciated

I tried checking the access db to see if there are any null dates but none all the dates are available, i found this solution online:

```
DateTime.ParseExact (txtPunchDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd" , null)
```

how would i incorporate that with my console application??
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [MS Access represents its `datetime` data type as a `double`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210276):

- The [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) (zero point) of the MS calendar is `30 December 1899 00:00:00`
- The integer portion of the `double` is the offset in days from the epoch, and
- The fractional portion of the `double` is the fractional part of the day.

Per the specification, the domain of the date portion of an MS Access `datetime` is

- lower bound: `1 January 100`
- upper bound: `31 December 9999`

And since the domain of a SQL Server `datetime` is:

- lower bound: `1 January 1753`
- upper bound: `31 December 9999`

any dates in your MS Access database prior to 1 January 1753 are going to cause problems. You need to find the bogus data and fix it. A couple of approaches:

- In your access database, create a view/query to present the data in a form palatable to SQL Server. Then, bulk load from that into SQL Server.
- Often, since it's pretty much a foregone conclusion that your source data is dirty/corrupted, when bulk loading data into SQL Server, one will bulk load the source data into a working table where all the columns are nullable, of type `varchar` types and that has no constraints/keys. Once that's done, then run a stored procedure that does the necessary cleanup and massaging of the data prior to moving it to its proper home.

Comment: I checked the access db there is no date less than 1 January 1753 sooo why am I still getting this error??